# Filter Sub-Collection of Collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
class Customer
{
   public int IdCustomer {get; set}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Expertise> Expertises {get; set;}
}

class Expertise
{
   public int IdExpertise {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<SubExpertise> SubExpertises {get; set;}
}

class SubExpertise
{
   public int IdSubExpertise { get; set;}
   public int IdExpertise {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public virtual Expertise Expertise {get; set;}
}
```

**How I can filter a *SubExpertise* using a IQueryable, and keep the filter condition? Basically I want to filter by *SubExpertise*, but keeping the possibilty to add more filters in the query**

**Example:** I wanna all customers that have a SubExpertise 'x' or 'y'. Keep in mind that SubExpertise is a sub-collection of a collection (Expertise). And that I can have new filters after this.

Comment: What is behind your IQueryable? Does it need to be a condition that is supported by Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes. Basically I have a lot of conditions that come from interface (filters) and I check which conditions are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after a method to build the expressions dynamically. You could use a predicate builder to do the job. My favorite is [this one](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

Using this little gem you can do this:

```
var pred = PredicateBuilder.Create<SubExpertise>(s => s.Description == "x");
pred = pred.Or(s => s.Description == "y");

var customers = db.Customers
                  .Where(c => c.Expertises
                               .Any(e => e.SubExpertises.AsQueryable()
                                          .Any(pred)));
```

`e.SubExpertises` must be cast to `IQueryable` because it's compile-time type is `ICollection`, and the extension method `Any` that fits `ICollection` doesn't accept an `Expression` but a `Func`, so it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pattern like this for resuable filters, defining the filters as Expressions

```
public static class SubExpertiseFilter
{
    public static Expression<SubExpertise, bool> XorY =
         se => se.Description == "X" || se.Description == "Y";

}
```

Then if I want to apply it:

```
public IQueryable<Expertise> ApplyXorYFilter(IQueryable<Expertise> expertises, bool appyXorY)
{
    if(applyXorY)
    {
        expertises = expertises.Any(e => e.Subexpertises.AsQueryable().Any(SubExpertiseFilter.XorY);
    }

    return expertises;
}
```

Or just do it inline where you need it.

The "AsQueryable" is needed to use the expression inside another expression so that EF is happy with it, otherwise the compiler expects a function there and that isn't something EF can turn into SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a list `customers`

```
var filteredCustomers = from customer in customers
                        where customer.Expertises.Any(e => e.Subexpertises.Any(s => IsXOrY(s)))
                        select customer;
```

You can add any filter conditions in `IsXOrY`: (and you should rename it)

```
bool IsXOrY(SubExpertise subExpertise)
{
    check if the SubExpertise is 'x' or 'y'
    check if the SubExpertise meets other criteria
    return true if this SubExpertise meets all your criteria
}
```

Comment: This doesn't run with an EF LINQ query. It wil complain that `IsXOrY` can't be translated into SQL.